# Discours rapporté dans le domaine professionnel

Tags: style-de-rédaction

Est-ce que l'usage du discours rapporté est utile dans le domaine professionnel ? Dans les rapports , les comptes rendus… ? Si oui quelques exemples de son usage dans un compte rendu ou un rapport ?

Comment: Bienvenue. La réponse à votre question relève du point de vue personnel. Si vous le jugez utile utilisez-le, sinon pas la peine. À vous de voir

Comment: C'est fréquent dans le cadre des relations sociales, notamment dans les procès verbaux des réunions entre l'employeur et les représentants du personnel (CE, CHSCT...).

Comment: Le discours rapporté est utilisé seulement pour reproduire les phrases d'une personne. Cela se fait dans toute sorte de documents rédigés dans le  domaine professionel, entre autres, les rapports annuels, les compte-rendus, etc. etc. Souvent, un PDG dira des choses au cours de l'année qui seront ensuite reprises dans des textes écrits, Il n'y a de règle fixe dans ce domaine. Aussi, c'est très utilisé dans les briefs, surtout juridiques (plaidoyers).

Answer (score 1):

Tout d'abord, tout dépend du contexte.

Si c'est un compte-rendu de réunion, il va de soit que l'on va parler de ce que le chef de réunion a décidé et de ce que les participants ont dit d'intéressant qui va dans le sens de l'ordre du jour.

Ensuite, il ne me semble pas qu'il soit usuel d'utiliser le discours rapporté dans des documents comme les rapports annuels par exemple.

En effet, un rapport annuel traduit les données de l'entreprise, ce que l'entreprise à mené sur une année, c'est à dire le résultat des efforts de tous les employés, y compris les dirigeants. Sans preuve à l'appui, j'affirme donc qu'un rapport annuel est impersonnel et que le discours rapporté ne peut donc y avoir sa place.

Answer (score 0):

Pour inclure le discours des autres dans son propre compte-rendu, il semble utile

- d'éliminer les préambules et formules de politesse,
- d'extraire les phrases fortes ; en général elles seront mises *en italique*,
- de condenser les autres parties en utilisant la contraction de texte pour avoir un résumé concis et dense.

... et surtout de citer ses sources, par respect pour leurs auteurs.